# line chart with log y axis and two series gets clipped

Tags: echarts

I am trying to make a line chart using echarts. The chart has a log scale on the `y` axis and has two series. The code is shown below (hopefully it will work, and is also [available on codepen](https://codepen.io/punkish/pen/MWzPdQR).

Strangely, the chart gets clipped. It is the second series (blue line) that causes the `y` axis scale fron 0 to 10 even though it should really be 0 to 1000 (because of the values in the first series, the red line). You can click on the blue key in the legend to turn it off and the scale will adjust to show the entire red line series.

```js
option = {
    title: {
        text: `occurence of 'formica' in text by year`,
        left: 'center'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        formatter: '{b}<hr>{a0}: {c0}<br/>{a1}: {c1}'
    },
    legend: {
        left: 'left',
        orient: 'vertical',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: '#444'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        name: 'x',
        splitLine: { show: false },
        data: [
            1841, 1846, 1850, 1851, 1853,
            1855, 1857, 1859, 1860, 1861,
            1862, 1863, 1866, 1877, 1884,
            1886, 1887, 1890, 1893, 1894,
            1895, 1896, 1902, 1904, 1905,
            1910, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1915,
            1920, 1922, 1924, 1926, 1928,
            1932, 1949, 1950, 1953, 1955,
            1956, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1975,
            1979, 1990, 1992, 1993, 1997,
            2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005,
            2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010,
            2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
            2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020,
            2021, 2022, 2023
        ]
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'log',
        minorSplitLine: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'withImages',
            type: 'line',
            data: [
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,
                  0,  5,   0,  0,  1,
                225,  0, 139,  0,  0,
                 12, 17,  16, 60,  5,
                 14, 25, 129, 23, 73,
                 36, 74,  49, 96, 27,
                386, 50,   0
            ],
            color: '#00f',
            lineStyle: {
                color: '#00f',
                width: 1
            },
            clip: true
        },
        {
            name: 'total',
            type: 'line',
            data: [
                  3,   2,   2,  26,   5, 
                  7,  27,  30,   4,   9, 
                 18,   4,  12,   1,   2, 
                 12,   2,   5,   4,   9, 
                  3,   1,   3,  14,  10, 
                  1,   1,   3,   7,   5, 
                  1,   8,   1,   5,   5, 
                  2,   3,   1,   2,   3, 
                  1,   2,   1,   2,   2, 
                136,  27,   3,   1,   1, 
                251,  14, 141,   2,  62, 
                 16,  79,  42, 141, 111, 
                 62, 100, 137,  54, 139, 
                166,  87,  79, 142,  84, 
                907,  79,   3
            ],
            color: '#f00',
            lineStyle: {
                color: '#f00',
                width: 1
            },
            clip: true
        }
    ]
};

const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('graphdiv'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.3/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="graphdiv" style="width: 100%;height:200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the log scale has issues with the 0 values in your series. I exchanged all 0 values with 0.1 which yields the expected [result](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-nest&edit=1&reset=1&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTtJgDYFMAuZdLM7fADzGIANgBjBgVwCd9oH9ZgAzWAOS9grALYQGAQwGwIcMFTCwARgE9Yq_JNa0ANKXKYCvGoK7QFrAQcwBffRixhgwXJBDFUjw2FYQA5v74rMQCkpQQAM4CDoaYwmKSYJahSMq2ADwAFqwAfEiSAAy2ngzFGcqsAPT5kgCMJcgMDdbesPY2sARB0AAmnp1kxqYCwzGDWCIQHCMAbsGQUrjjbWTKIr3BAOoQvWBZxHWxceusm6wASpK9EMyRxACsx4an5wDCriKhAMQALP-tMgdNqUACCEXuJFWTlUICIZiS-H8IlUKzisGgklE8IElDRcUiIFwEDAABk5PCkLBIllgAB3Yi8SS4SLcYHo3pJSTEADaE0MdQAHL8jrAhb8AGy6MWCh6FaVCh6ixUAZme6JlDyemoA7ArZQBOfUS-UyiVHfnkIUSgBMxrVZqlMp1eplwvV6KFgqdXtdQoNpv9Dv9vw9cX92v9PoDdrFAdDccKT0tZDqBrqgfTsbTdWD6YTOeT0IFBptmZt2dLBdL0ZtgrDJZVld-RrjcoVBoeea1DatnejD3rbdbaZNHZ1RY1WDTOpHBoDHdLi7zBr1KawZcKps3os3Ds3Cc3k6nsE3Ts3rs3Q83rbLGd7ZDvu8KdVjd_3L8PL-PU7v55fl4vteL63oUZYPhuYHPhW0pljaKqWgAup07JYP4fj9FC6LDKEKoAKT4oYfj-FkIy_ARvbrMkwCiLhFGWgwMBgJIcikpIyj4LgxC-Mw-AoeqqjglEAzFtgsI4rgwD-IR5DiNAIgAMpEiS5LQJS66YDS9LcawvGWrY_GdKyfj4JCfKiV4J4YliOJ0iSWQAJKiJIQTRBBmBgOJoTEmpMkclyvIaXEhQAHSiqF4VhdKEXRVFQWGDFsCJclUVJXFolTilkXZbFFoZRqWW5UVaV5VZCWpYVJVFfF5CVXV6VlbVFXNTlVU1WQ9WtTF7VYJ1xXdfl6KJbA2qYMNw2lY1p42qNiW5q2VVjQ1U1itmrpik6Y6YD-jV1IekY2reDo6mqPWwCqTo6gmsAttKBrnmug3kCq3rSu2vVhUFiHubAjGSSEgjfFuvB-XEPn4ApnkECJK1_V8gPA6DU52XsBxikFqFTgwxIeNgul8aJmPkJZJ6YtioTOMxyw_Z5cLeRSSPkJyzGBU9hgOpgsac9Kp5Ott0pnbA602utKqmpg12wK2Z1CjzN086-cuitzsAy1zp5y6N8tYNLbPPUrcsc3tCumoLytiobcvrSNAt66mctDpg5ta9qgvqxzFsbpbqt29Ocvq-b6uxj1uZ8yL3tOwbPsrTNyvG2KIr-zztq2ytG087OPO_NmidinUopnSnYpbgqKrrQ8BYqrrK11BKfOCutmcJ1z7rR1NAaNwt51fT9cMAwI3y8FujNDBSkOqNDWFTX3PxD4UI9xCj-yHBjvc4zpemE50yFoLYADcQA).

I dont know how log scale axes should behave with zero or negative values. If it is not intended you might want to file a bug issue on [github](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues).

Comment: Right. Log axes can't handle zero at all (`convertToPixel(0)` is `-Infinity`). Probably, OP's intention was to have no data at those points [codepen](https://codepen.io/punkish/pen/MWzPdQR?editors=0010)

Comment: yes, replacing `0` with `null` fixed it. Strange though, I really wanted `0`. I know that the number of times the term occurred in those years is `0`. By  replacing `0` with `null`, I an effectively implying that the frequency of the term is unknown… oh well